# MySql attach multiply group to user

Tags: mysql, database-design

I got a users table and movies table, each user could watch more then one movie.

Now I want to find all the users who watched particular movie,
How should my tables looks like in MySql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you need 3 tables. The first two are users and movies, they would, in a very basic form, look like this:

```
user
  id
  name

movie
  id
  title
```

Since many users can watch many movies and the same movie can be watched by multiple users, there's a many-to-many relationship there. To define such a relationship in MySQL, you need a third table called a join table, that knows which user watched which movie (I called this user_movies but you might want to go with a different name):

```
user_movies
  user_id
  movie_id
```

To know who watched a movie called Spaceballs, you need a query like this:

```
SELECT u.name FROM user u 
  JOIN user_movies um ON um.user_id = u.id 
  JOIN movie m ON um.movie_id = m.id
    WHERE m.title = 'Spaceballs'
```

Comment: Excellent explanation - Queries with joins were a bane of mine for a while .. now to move on to DB stored functions :) .. my brother keeps touting MS stuff because he basically has DLL's written in the DB for data access/parsing :)

Comment: There are many types of joins in SQL, here's a basic tutorial on them: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp